# Unir columnas en Python por ID

Tags: python, pandas, concatenación

Buen día a todos.

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo los siguientes datos:

```
    lifestore_products = [
    [1, 'Termo marca Thermo', 319, 'Hogar', 20],
    [2, 'Control PS', 4239, 'Juegos', 1],
    [3, 'Silla de escritorio', 49, 'Oficina', 185]]
```

y después tengo

```
lifestore_sales = [
    [1, 1, 5, '25/07/2019', 0],
    [2, 1, 5, '27/07/2019', 0],
    [3, 2, 5, '25/02/2019', 0]]
```

quisiera unir en un nuevo data frame, por medio de la primera columna ya que ese es el ID del producto.

PD. esto es opcional, pero me gustaría saber como ponerle nombres a las columnas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo unir DataFrames en Pandas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403245/c%c3%b3mo-unir-dataframes-en-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que como estás hablando de **DataFrame** y nombres de columnas, estás usando `pandas`. Hacer ambas cosas es sencillo, te quedo el código explicado:

### 1. Creamos los DataFrames y ponemos nombres a las columnas.

```
import pandas as pd

lifestore_products = [
[1, 'Termo marca Thermo', 319, 'Hogar', 20],
[2, 'Control PS', 4239, 'Juegos', 1],
[3, 'Silla de escritorio', 49, 'Oficina', 185]]


lifestore_sales = [
    [1, 1, 5, '25/07/2019', 0],
    [2, 1, 5, '27/07/2019', 0],
    [3, 2, 5, '25/02/2019', 0]]

# Creamos dos Dataframes, y con el parámetro columns fijamos el nombre de las columnas.

lifestore_products = pd.DataFrame(lifestore_products, columns=['id', 'nombre', 'precio', 'apartado', 'cantidad'])
lifestore_sales = pd.DataFrame(lifestore_sales, columns=['id', 'tipo', 'grupo', 'fecha', 'devolucion'])
```

#### Explicación

- `pd.DataFrame()`: Es clase, que crea un objeto **DataFrame**, con el parámetro **columns** que es opcional, podemos pasarle el nombre de las columnas de dicho DataFrame.
- En el caso de que se nos olvide pasarle las columnas al crear un DataFrame, no importa, al ser un objeto `columns` es un atributo de dicho objeto por lo que se lo podemos pasar cuando queramos, aquí te enseño otra forma:

```
#No le pasamos las columnas.
lifestore_products = pd.DataFrame(lifestore_products)

#Llamamos al atributo columns y le pasamos los nombres de las columnas
lifestore_products.columns = ['id', 'nombre', 'precio', 'apartado', 'cantidad']
```

### 2. Juntamos ambos DataFrames por ID.

```
df_product_sales = pd.merge(lifestore_products, lifestore_sales, on='id', how='left')
```

#### Explicación

- Los dos primeros parámetros de esta función son los dos dataframes que queremos unir, en este caso **lifestore_products** y **lifestore_sales**
- Parámetro `on`: indicamos el nombre de la columna por la que queremos juntar ambos dataframes.
- Parámetro `how`: el tipo de unión que quremos hacer, por defecto es *inner* pero también puedes usar *left*, *right* o *outer*.

### Output

Este será el aspecto de tu **DataFrame** una vez realizadas las anteriores operaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Creo que un poco de lo que estas buscando esta por acá.. espero que te sirva, éxitos!

```
productos = len(lifestore_products)
print ("cantidad de productos" + str(productos))
for i in range(productos):
    print ("producto id: "+str(i)+" ->"+            str(lifestore_products[i]))
    if lifestore_products[i][0] == lifestore_sales[i][0]:
        print("true")
        lifestore_products[i].append(lifestore_sales[i])
    print ("producto id: "+str(i)+" ->"+            str(lifestore_products[i]))
```

Da como resultado:

```
producto id: 2 ->[3, 'Silla de escritorio', 49, 'Oficina', 185, [3, 2, 5, '25/02/2019', 0]]
```

Otra forma de concatenarlos sin generar un array nuevo puede ser

```
        lifestore_products[i] = lifestore_products[i]+ lifestore_sales[i]
```

Esto dará:

```
producto id: 2 ->[3, 'Silla de escritorio', 49, 'Oficina', 185, 3, 2, 5, '25/02/2019', 0]
```