# ¿Cómo unir DataFrames en Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Si tengo distintos dataframes en `Pandas`, ¿Cómo puedo unirlos?

Por ejemplo me creo tres `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"fruta": ["manzana", "pera", "platano", "naranja", "aguacate"],
                    "precio": [0.20, 0.45, 0.15, 0.12, 0.62]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"stock": [10, 20, 25, 12, 40]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({"ventas_totales":[3, 5, 2, 3, 6],
                     "ingresos_ventas": [120, 110, 64,44, 147]})
```

¿Hay alguna forma de concatenarlos (unirlos) en `Pandas`, o es imposible y debería de usar un bucle `for`?

Y si tienen un Identificador *(ID)* **¿Es posible unirlos en base a una columna como en `SQL`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas tiene multiples formas de unir dataframes, dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, te vendrán mejor unas u otras. Paso a explicar las dos formas principales y sus resultados usando el ejemplo de la pregunta.

## concatenar

Si se quiere unir distintos DataFrames y todos tienen el mismo orden (es decir si los datos de la fila 1 del DataFrame 1, corresponde con la del DataFrame 2 y el DataFrame 3), se haría así:

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3], axis=1)
```

**Salida:**

```
      fruta  precio  stock  ventas_totales  ingresos_ventas
0   manzana    0.20     10               3              120
1      pera    0.45     20               5              110
2   platano    0.15     25               2               64
3   naranja    0.12     12               3               44
4  aguacate    0.62     40               6              147
```

Con `axix=1` indicamos que queremos unirlo por filas, si ponemos `axis=0` se uniría por columnas.

**Ventajas:**

- Rápido y sencillo
- Nos permite pasar una lista de DataFrames uniendo todo los que queramos. (muy usado cuando se almacenan dataframes en una lista con `.append()`

**Desventajas:**

- Los DataFrames tienen que tener el mismo número de filas
- Las filas deben tener los datos ordenados **ya que los une por el indice**

Un sinónimo de esta forma sería:

```
pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(df_3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

El resultado es el mismo, aunque como se puede comprobar es más tedioso de escribir

## Usar merge por ID

En este caso vamos a suponer que tenemos una columna con IDs que identifican cada fila, y que no están ordenadas, es decir, el ID de la fila 1 en el DataFrame 1, lo podemos encontrar en la fila *"X"* del DataFrame 2. Pongo el código de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
                    "fruta": ["manzana", "pera", "platano", "naranja", "aguacate"],
                    "precio": [0.20, 0.45, 0.15, 0.12, 0.62]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[5,4,3,2,1],
                     "stock": [10, 20, 25, 12, 40]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[4,2,5,1,3],
                     "ventas_totales":[3, 5, 2, 3, 6],
                     "ingresos_ventas": [120, 110, 64,44, 147]})
```

En este caso no podemos usar `pandas.concat()`. Para unir los dataframes podemos usar el método `.merge()` que es exactamente igual que la función `pandas.merge()`, y nos permitirá seleccionar la columna por la que queremos unir, y la forma de unión:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, on="id", how="left")
```

**Salida:**

```
   id     fruta  precio  stock
0   1   manzana    0.20     40
1   2      pera    0.45     12
2   3   platano    0.15     25
3   4   naranja    0.12     20
4   5  aguacate    0.62     10
```

Con el parámetro `on=` indicamos el nombre de la columna por la que queremos unir, y con el parámetro `how=` el tipo de unión que funciona igual que en `SQL`. Pandas soporta los tipo de unión `inner`, `left`, `right` outer`.

En el caso de que queramos hacer `merge()` de más de dos DataFrames, solo tenemos que ir encadenando métodos:

```
#unimos el primero al segundo y el resultado de dicha unión, le unimos el tercero
df_1.merge(df_2, on="id", how="left").merge(df_3, on="id", how="left")
```

**Salida:**

```
   id     fruta  precio  stock  ventas_totales  ingresos_ventas
0   1   manzana    0.20     40               3               44
1   2      pera    0.45     12               5              110
2   3   platano    0.15     25               6              147
3   4   naranja    0.12     20               3              120
4   5  aguacate    0.62     10               2               64
```

Incidir que con `merge()` podemos hacer distintos tipos de uniones, al estilo de `SQL`

Estos métodos son tremendamente útiles el saber usarlos bien en `Pandas`. Aquí quedo la documentación oficial de pandas, por si se quiere ampliar más y ver distintos parámetros:

- [Pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
- [Pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)