# Pandas: Combinar dataframe final previamente dividido

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un dataframe (df) con una estructura similar a ésta (es mucho más largo tanto en filas como columnas):

```
    Name       Team    Shots    Goals    Actions Games      Minutes
1   Player 1    ATL        5       3      20       2            15
2   Player 2    RMA        6       2      15       1            30
3   Player 3    RMA        3       3      16       1            20
4   Player 4    BAR        9       0      22       3            28
5   Player 5    ATL        8       1      19       2            32
```

Por distintos motivos tenido que filtrar creando otro dataframe solo las filas correspondientes a RMA en la columna Team y he modificado los valores de varias de sus columnas (Shots, Goals, Actions...). Digamos que a este dataframe lo he denominado df2.

El siguiente paso, que no doy con él por mi bajo conocimiento de código, sería tener un df final que incluya tanto los valores del df inicial como los que han sido trabajados en el df2. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que se respeten los valores iniciales del dataframe y a su vez se incluyan los valores del df2 y aparezcan en las mismas filas que se veían en el primer df? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo unir DataFrames en Pandas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403245/c%c3%b3mo-unir-dataframes-en-pandas)

Comment: He intentado con concat y merge y no logro que funcione bien porque por algún motivo que se me escapa, al utilizar merge me devuelve valores nulos en las columnas que no he modificado del primer dataframe al trabajar con el df2

Comment: tengo una forma de hacerlo pero no se que tan bien podria funcionar